# What are the colors on the globe in the 90s-00s Universal Studios logo?

Tags: credits

In the Universal Studios logo which appears at the very beginning of movies appearing [around the 90s-00s](http://www.closinglogos.com/page/Logo+Variations+-+Universal+Pictures), there's a colored globe.

My question is the significance of the colors on land. They don't appear to signify elevation or temperature or population density. Surely they came from somewhere and aren't just random noise!

[image: Universal logo]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a variation of the 70's logo, with brighter colors. You can see the previous logo show forests / deserts / mountains:

[image]

Now compare the same areas with the 90's logo ([according to this blog](http://mrmovierbknapp.blogspot.com/2013/02/movie-studio-logos.html) it started in 1997):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at current google earth maps and take into consideration desertification and other factors, the colors on the Universal logo seem to match the desert/green areas on earth. Green color shows forests, deserts are red.

[image: Globe pictures from google earth]